# Application slow after installation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, windows-8

I've created this WPF application and it's working fine and fast when running the release build from any folder.
Since it's done I made an installer (WiX) to install it into the program files folder. When I run my application from program files it's very slow and hangs all the time. Running as administrator makes it run normally again.
Why is this and how can I make it run normally without having to run as admin?

thanks.

Comment: did you sign your application?

Comment: It looks like a rights/permissions issue, check whether the app has all the rights it needs

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/6050724/847349, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2059410/847349 if those help

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by enabling `ClickOnce security settings` in project properties and selected option `This is a full trust application`.

Comment: Is there anything else that you did to fix this? I have the same issue, but I tried your solution and it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I found my issue. Adding "read only=true" to the sqlite connection I was making solved the issue.