# My C# app make an HTTP request when accessing Properties.Settings.Default.workingdirectory

Tags: c#, http

My application run on a citrix server and the port 80 is close.

In the application, the first time i try to read a setting or a resources, two HTTP request start, since the port is close, it take 30 seconds before the application continue. After that i can read setting without any request.

These are the two request
akamai-112.120.cache.videotron.ca  and  akamai-144.120.cache.videotron.ca

Exemple code:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt");
file.WriteLine("Before Properties: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

var chemin = Properties.Settings.Default.workingdirectory;

file.WriteLine("After Properties: "  + dateTime.Now.ToString());
file.Close();
```

In test.txt, there's 30 secondes between BEFORE and AFTER.
I have no idea what cause that.

Anybody have a clue?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use a progiler and step into `workingDirectory` to see what makes it slower? If it shows you just `clr` or something in the profiler try to use `procmon` on this process and see what is it doing when this line occurs.

Comment: Hi Some1Pr0, workingDirectory is a variable in the settings. I just read a string value.

Comment: I know but if it is a property it has a getter and than maybe it gets it from a file which might be locks/i dont know what, but you say that like takes 30 seconds so something else happens there.

Comment: I've find the getter and it just return the value. Thanks.

Comment: If you are debugging at the assembly level is there any instruction ehich takes really long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6042555/2223043)

i've add in my app.config, in the runtime section

```
generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"
```

It stop making http request.