# C# WPF really slow startup first time

Tags: .net, wpf, performance

I was adviced to just create a simple wpf application with a button to check the performance problems..
It is painfully slow to start only first time event in decent machines. 
I have built an executable in release mode optimised but first time is about 15 seconds disk IO is high during that time.. The second time it runs is faster less than 1 sec...
I believe that it is too much time...

I added a file app1.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

app1 isnt the name of the app.. but didnt help...

Any idea what to do ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF application slow on startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086692/wpf-application-slow-on-startup)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On some machines if you've never run a WPF app since bootup the application startup can be painful.  You could add a "quickstart" by running any WPF app (without needing to display a window -- just reference one) in your startup folder.  That will ensure the dot-net framework is fully loaded and your app should load faster, though this will slow bootup a bit.

Comment: thats a nice idea... a bit overkill though..imagine every application to do this

Comment: You only need a single app that does it, and every WPF app will load faster.  Many apps use this method -- java does, for example; so does Microsoft Office, VMWare, and many others.  We've used this method with our commercial applications because of the exact issue you describe, but we do it in a service.

Comment: so it could be a simple service that does nothing ? just have some framework references?

Comment: Yes. We used a single line of code: Window window = new Window(); and that was enough to load most of the WPF assemblies and massively sped up app load time.

Comment: Agreed that it's not fabulous, Microsoft should provide official solution, but it's what there is (we met with Microsoft to discuss...).  It's especially a problem when you use framework that runs in the service context because no one ever runs WPF in that context so the first time it can take very long.

Comment: @Parhs Totally! Because of stuff like this, my reboot takes ~10 minutes these days (from power on to being usable - not showing the logon screen, but actually usable). It used to exceed 15 minutes, but then I went in and removed a large number of those "quickstart" solutions from autorun. Ironic how they make system start most definitely un-quick.

Comment: @romkyns, some quickstarts are indeed obnoxious, especially if they are loading things that only they use, disguising a hoggish application by moving most of its load time to startup.  However, this suggestion is just for the dot-net framework to preload, and once loaded, even 20 more quickstarts like this would load in a small fraction of a second and take up almost no memory.

Comment: I have written a program which simply loads all assemblies from GAC into memory, so all programs can benefit from it. I can easily eat 500 MB of RAM with the effect that a lot of memory will be swapped back to disk. I'm really not sure whether that's a good approach...

Comment: @Thomas W, that's not a good approach.  Many assemblies in the GAC are only needed rarely and such a program could use far more than 500 MB of RAM if enough assemblies are in the GAC.  Loading the parts of the .NET framework needed to display a window uses far less memory and loads assemblies that are almost definitely going to be used a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [NGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to speed up the first run of your application.

Comment: NGEN will only provide a very slight speed increase.  Most of the issue is that the dot-net frameworks have not yet loaded.  Notice that the subsequent times he runs his program it's much faster, yet the JIT still has to run again.